# Python; Determining and adding noise to image segments

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-image

In order to get the grips of coding I decided to determine the standard deviation in a certain area of a x-ray picture using Python/Numpy/SKimage. To start with I decided to use thresholding in order to get a part of the image, this wasn't hard.

However, at this point everything above/below the threshold is zero at thus is included in the measurements I would like to do. Thus I need to exclude the data below/above the threshold.

I imagine it would be able to create a map or exclude certain value’s or possibly more exotic solutions. However, at this point I’m thinking I might be heading in the wrong direction.

My basics -

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import imageio

image = imageio.imread('thx.jpg', as_gray=True)
image = image.astype('int32')

test1 = np.array(image, copy=True)
test1[image >= 100] = 0
```

I'm looking for a way to exclude the data above/below the threshold.  Could someone provide me with a small push in the right direction?

Edit: It's nice to have an easy day at work once in a while; A sub-solution to my problem is adding all values greater/smaller then to a list and determining the standard deviation from there. This however leaves me with the problem of implementing the noise ***to*** the image segments.

```
im_row = image.shape[0]
im_col = image.shape[1]
grthen = []
smlthen = []

for i in range(0,im_col-1):
    for j in range(0,im_row-1):
        if (j > 100):
           grthen.append(j)
        else:
            smlthen.append(j)

print(np.std(smlthen))
print(np.std(grthen))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you set all those pixels to zero, then try to get statistics from them. Instead, realize that `test1[image < 100]` only refers to those pixels below the threshold... so I think you can just get your statistics from that, e.g. with `np.std(test1[image < 100])`.

You might like to take a look at [`scikit-image`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/0.13.x/auto_examples/xx_applications/plot_thresholding.html), which contains lots of tools for thresholding, dealing with binary images, using those as masks (which is essentially what you're doing), etc.

Comment: Somehow I keep looking past these pragmatic/simple solutions! Thanks:)

Answer (score 2):

> ... determine the standard deviation in a certain area of a x-ray picture using Python/Numpy/SKimage.

Let us first generate a mock image:

```
In [18]: import numpy as np

In [19]: rows, cols = 4, 4

In [20]: image = np.linspace(0, 1, rows*cols).reshape(rows, cols)

In [21]: np.set_printoptions(precision=2)

In [22]: image
Out[22]: 
array([[0.  , 0.07, 0.13, 0.2 ],
       [0.27, 0.33, 0.4 , 0.47],
       [0.53, 0.6 , 0.67, 0.73],
       [0.8 , 0.87, 0.93, 1.  ]])
```

And let us define the region of interest through double thresholding:

```
In [25]: low, high = .3, .6

In [26]: mask = np.logical_and(image > low, image < high)

In [27]: mask
Out[27]: 
array([[False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False]])
```

[Boolean indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays) is a possible way to compute the standard deviation over the region of interest:

```
In [29]: image[mask]
Out[29]: array([0.33, 0.4 , 0.47, 0.53])

In [30]: np.std(image[mask])
Out[30]: 0.07453559924999299
```

Setting the unwanted pixels to `np.nan` and using NumPy's [`nanstd`](https://www.numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.nanstd.html) to compute the standard deviation would be another way to go:

```
In [32]: test1 = np.where(mask, image, np.nan)

In [33]: test1
Out[33]: 
array([[ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
       [ nan, 0.33, 0.4 , 0.47],
       [0.53,  nan,  nan,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan]])

In [34]: np.nanstd(test1)
Out[34]: 0.07453559924999299
```

> ... the problem of implementing the noise to the image segments.

You could use scikit-images's [`random_noise`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#skimage.util.random_noise) to generate a noisy image and then filter out those pixels outside the region of interest through NumPy's [`where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
In [36]: from skimage.util import random_noise

In [37]: noisy = random_noise(image)

In [38]: noisy
Out[38]: 
array([[0.14, 0.07, 0.17, 0.29],
       [0.34, 0.39, 0.38, 0.53],
       [0.66, 0.73, 0.66, 0.67],
       [0.73, 0.98, 1.  , 0.88]])

In [39]: np.where(mask, noisy, image)
Out[39]: 
array([[0.  , 0.07, 0.13, 0.2 ],
       [0.27, 0.39, 0.38, 0.53],
       [0.66, 0.6 , 0.67, 0.73],
       [0.8 , 0.87, 0.93, 1.  ]])
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. This is very usefull in the bigger picture I have! (No pun intended:))